# Delphi - Manage Indy TCPServer connections with a Listview

Tags: delphi, listview, tcp, indy

I need to send a string message from IdTCPServer to a specific connected IdTCPClient. In the beginning I was using a Listbox, so I added the hostname to the listbox when client connected and remove when disconnect. At that time, Remy Lebeau give me this tip:

```
procedure TfrmMain.sendButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Index: Integer;
  Ctx: TIdContext;
begin
  Index := ListBox.ItemIndex;
  if Index = -1 then Exit;
  Context := TIdContext(ListBox.Items.Objects[Index]);
  // use Context as needed...
end;
```

But now I am using a Listview, with pre-added hostnames. So I just change the listbox item image status when clients connect or disconnect. Now I am trying something like this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.TCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    var
      Host: String;
      LItem: TListItem;
    begin
      Host := UpperCase(GStack.HostByAddress(Ctxt.Binding.PeerIP));
      LItem := lvwPCList.FindCaption(0, Host, False, True, False);
      if (LItem <> nil) then LItem.Data := AContext.Data;
    end
  );
end;
```

And once I linked the Listview Item with the Context data, I am trying to send the message direct to client:

```
procedure TfrmMain.SendMessage(const Item: TListItem; const Msg: String);
var
  Ctx: TIdContext;
begin
  if (Trim(Msg) = '') then Exit;
  Ctx := TIdContext(Item.Data);
  try
    Ctx.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(Msg);
  except
  end;
end;

SendMessage(Listview.Selected, 'test');
```

I can compile this code, but the message never reachs client. Please, what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assigning the value of the `TIdContext.Data` property to the `TListItem.Data` property, but you are casting `TListItem.Data` to `TIdContext` when it is not pointing at a `TIdContext` to begin with.

You should also take into account the condition that a client may have disconnected before you have a chance to update the `TListView`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
procedure TfrmMain.TCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  LHost: string;
begin
  LHost := UpperCase(GStack.HostByAddress(AContext.Binding.PeerIP));
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    var
      LItem: TListItem;
    begin
      LItem := lvwPCList.FindCaption(0, LHost, False, True, False);
      if (LItem <> nil) then LItem.Data := AContext;
    end
  );
end;

procedure TfrmMain.TCPServerDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    var
      LItem: TListItem;
    begin
      LItem := lvwPCList.FindData(0, AContext, True, False);
      if (LItem <> nil) then LItem.Data := nil;
    end
  );
end;

procedure TfrmMain.SendMessage(const Item: TListItem; const Msg: String);
var
  Ctx: TIdContext;
  List: TIdContextList;
begin
  if (Item = nil) then Exit;
  Ctx := TIdContext(Item.Data);
  if (Ctx = nil) then Exit;
  if (Trim(Msg) = '') then Exit;
  try
    List := TCPServer.Contexts.LockList;
    try
      if List.IndexOf(Ctx) <> -1 then
        Ctx.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(Msg);
    finally
      TCPServer.Contexts.UnlockList;
    end;
  except
  end;
end;
```

```
SendMessage(Listview.Selected, 'test');
```

That being said, depending on how your communication protocol is actually implemented, you probably should not be calling `WriteLn()` outside of the `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` event, otherwise you risk corrupting any data that `OnExecute` may be writing at the same time that the main thread is trying to write.  If this is the case, then you should implement a per-client queue of outbound data any have the `OnExecute` event send that data when it is safe to do so, eg:

```
uses
  ..., IdThreadSafe;

type
  TMyContext = class(TIdServerContext)
  public
    constructor Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    Queue: TIdThreadSafeStringList;
  end;

constructor TMyContext.Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil);
begin
  inherited;
  Queue := TIdThreadSafeStringList.Create;
end;

destructor TMyContext.Destroy;
begin
  Queue.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TCPServer.ContextClass := TMyContext;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.TCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  LHost: string;
begin
  LHost := UpperCase(GStack.HostByAddress(AContext.Binding.PeerIP));
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    var
      LItem: TListItem;
    begin
      LItem := lvwPCList.FindCaption(0, LHost, False, True, False);
      if (LItem <> nil) then LItem.Data := AContext;
    end
  );
end;

procedure TfrmMain.TCPServerDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    var
      LItem: TListItem;
    begin
      LItem := lvwPCList.FindData(0, AContext, True, False);
      if (LItem <> nil) then LItem.Data := nil;
    end
  );
end;

procedure TfrmMain.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Ctx: TMyContext;
  Queue: TStringList;
  List: TStringList;
begin
  ...
  Ctx := TMyContext(AContext);
  List := nil;
  try
    Queue := Ctx.Queue.Lock;
    try
      if Queue.Count > 0 then
      begin
        List := TStringList.Create;
        List.Assign(Queue);
        Queue.Clear;
      end;
    finally
      Ctx.Queue.Unlock;
    end;
    if List <> nil then
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(List);
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;

procedure TfrmMain.SendMessage(const Item: TListItem; const Msg: String);
var
  Ctx: TIdContext;
  List: TIdContextList;
begin
  if (Item = nil) then Exit;
  Ctx := TIdContext(Item.Data);
  if (Ctx = nil) then Exit;
  if (Trim(Msg) = '') then Exit;
  try
    List := TCPServer.Contexts.LockList;
    try
      if List.IndexOf(Ctx) <> -1 then
        TMyContext(Ctx).Queue.Add(Msg);
    finally
      TCPServer.Contexts.UnlockList;
    end;
  except
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Remy Lebeau, it worked like a charm! Thank you again! Btw, do you think this is a better approach than "looping" the Contexts.LockList and compare hostname?

Comment: I am using Indy from Delphi XE3 and seems IdContextThreadList is missing. Must I update Indy ?

Comment: Yes, looking for a specific object instance that represents a specific client is a better choice, and is faster than string comparisons. As for `TIdContextThreadList`, it was added in the XE4 release of Indy (`TIdContextList` was added in XE6). In older versions, use `TThreadList` and `TList` instead, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

In your listbox code you appear to be storing **TIdContext** references in your item "object" slots:

```
Context := TIdContext(ListBox.Items.Objects[Index]);
```

But in your listview code you are storing the **Data** member of a **TIdContext**, which you are then incorrectly casting as a **TIdContext** in your *SendMessage()* method:

```
  // In TCPServerConnect():

    if (LItem <> nil) then LItem.Data := AContext.Data;


  ...

  // In SendMessage():

    Ctx := TIdContext(Item.Data);    // But Item.Data doesn't hold a TIdContext!!!
```

For direct equivalence with your listbox code, that first line in your **TCPServerConnect** method should be:

```
 if (LItem <> nil) then LItem.Data := AContext;
```

Comment: Nice catch. I missed the `Data := Data` assignment.